# How to change default viewport shading in 2.8?

Tags: lighting

Is it possible to change the default mesh color/shading in 2.8 to be more like 2.79?
I'm finding it hard to see finer detail in 2.8.
On the left is 2.8 and the right is 2.79[image]

Comment: Try this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132494/noob-question-how-to-make-objects-brighter-during-design/132496#132496

Answer (score 3):

To change Default Studio lightning without using Matcaps/Shading modes:

Go to ***Edit > User Preferences > Lights*** and choose **Edit Studio Lights**.

Now you can change all 4 lights. Options are self-explanatory.

After making dreamed setup - **Save as Studio Light** and **Save Preferences**.

You can even download saved setup and share it.

[image: final]

Here is something similar to 2.79. Probably a bit to shiny:

[image: old]

Comment: Thanks, I have been messing with the studio lights. It does help a bit, but the mesh still looked too bright. I just found the solution this morning in the shading pop-up. https://imgur.com/a/PcKZqTP. Turning on matcap here and saving it as default brings the viewport back very close to 2.79

Comment: @rwana yeah, matcaps and cavity is also good way to change objects visibility, but remember that they can slightly influence performance. Try messing with Ambient Color in Studio Lights to make it darker.

Answer (score 0):

install the studiolight
https://file.io/big2JKySVup4

and to make blender more like 2.7
go to preferences ->viewport ->viewport anti-aliasing  change it to no anti-aliasing
and uncheck overlay,edit mode .
[image]

[image]