# How to adjust edit view settings?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am absolutely new to Blender, moving from SketchUp. I find it hard to see where are my edges and faces are with the default settings. Where can I set how edges and faces are rendered while editing? Here is an example:

[image]

I would like to have contours and less opaque faces. Where can I set those?

Comment: In my answer I assumed that you are already aware of different visualization modes in the viewport by pressing <key>z</key> you get into wireframe mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Noob question: How to make objects brighter during design](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132494/noob-question-how-to-make-objects-brighter-during-design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer I assume that you are already aware of different visualization modes in the viewport by pressing <kbd>z</kbd> (wireframe mode) and pressing <kbd>alt+z</kbd> to switch back and cycle between Textured and solid mode as for <kbd>shift+z</kbd> for render mode.

An alternative way to get semi transparent objects in your viewport is to change the Material's Settings > Viewport Color.

So create a new material for your object and its Material Tab > Settings > Viewport Color set the color (with the alpha transparency) of your choice.

Then go to Mesh Tab > Display and enable Wire to have the closest you can get to an outline.

Important note, is to set your render to **Cycles** in order to have access to these material's settings.

see the image below:

[image: Set Viewport Transparency]

Comment: Thanks! I tried adjusting those settings, but it is not quite like I would like it to be. I maybe too used to SketchUp, I would like to see those edges in some contrasting colour in solid mode as well, but I guess it is not possible.